# Proving that the index is two of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to the following theorem:

> let $G=\textrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ and $N=\{A\in G: \, \det(A)>0\}$. Prove that $G/N \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ .

In the solution they said that $[G:N]=2$ without proving it. How did they do it? It is trivial?

Comment: elements of $G$ are invertible matrices, so their determinant is non-zero

Comment: $N$ is the kernel of the homomorphism mapping $A$ to sign$(\det(A))\in\{1,-1\}$; $\det$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to $\Bbb R^*$ because determinant is multiplicative

Answer (score 5):

Consider the composition of homomorphisms
\begin{align}
GL(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2
\end{align}

where the first is the determinant, the second sending an element of $\mathbb{R^*} = \mathbb{R} \setminus 0$ to its sign.

This is surjective, with kernel $N$, so by the first isomorphism theorem, $GL(n,\mathbb{R}) / N \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$

Comment: or you can directly map to $\{\pm 1\}$ and use the sign of the determinant for your homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *trivial*, but it's not too tough. You've gotta prove that besides $N$, there is a single other coset in $G/N$. This'll be the coset consisting of matrices with negative determinant. So you've gotta pick some matrix $m \in G$ with a negative determinant, and show that *every* matrix with negative determinant is in the coset $mN$, i.e. that for your fixed $m$ every matrix with negative determinant can be written as $mn$ for some matrix $n$ with positive determinant. Hint: choose a really easy $m$ like
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & \dotsb & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \dotsb & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dotsb & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think of it that way, we identify all matrices with positive determinant so we think of them as one element (formally thay map to the same element in the quotient group). What would be the second element? For this recall that $G$ can't have matrices with zero determinant.
This should give you understanding of the quotient group and why it has two elements.